# Software Install Dies at Setting Environment Variables when Run as Administrator

Tags: administrator, environment-variables, installer

I have engineers that must install a program that sets Environment Variables, but we don't give our users Admin Privileges. We set up local accounts with Admin Privileges they use to install programs.

The install will never complete because it won't allow the Environment Variables to be changed even when installing a program using Run as Administrator.

Is there a workaround for this without temporarily adding the users to the Admin Group? The only users I've had installing the program are running Windows 7.

Comment: Have an Administrator add these system variables before the device is assigned to a non-Administrator user.

Comment: I don't know what they are. They may even be the same as the first time they are set during install. This program is modified and the engineers must test it, so they install it again and again. Each time the install fails once the install program tries to modify the system variables. 

My workaround is add them to the admin group until they finish installing the program and then removing them from the group. I'm trying to find a solution that keeps IT from having to do this each time.